# Who was this female Marvel character in a Hulk story

Tags: marvel, character-identification

This female character appeared in a Hulk story that I read back in 80's.

The lady in question was some kind of movie producer from another realm and had a purse that seemed to contain a Universe (or maybe it was a portal to a Universe). She was wearing gold-colored clothes and headgear that was shaped a bit like a mohawk (-hairstyle).

She had some small pet (or robot) companion that she occasionally spoke to in an alien language. Also, if I remember correctly she came to earth to make a documentary and she was, technically speaking, neither a villainess nor a heroine.

What is the name of this character?

Comment: It is almost certainly a character from the Mojoverse, but I don't know who.

Comment: My first thought is that this sounds like an amalgam of Mojo, Spiral, and Storm.

Comment: Thanks James & neilfein, I took a look at the Mojo character in Wikipedia. It seems that this character is not from Mojoverse, because she came to earth to make a documentary, and not for the purpose of recording gladiator-type fighting (I have updated my question).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The documentary film-making is the key. I think you mean [Bereet](http://marvel.wikia.com/Bereet_%28Earth-616%29).

> A prominent techno-artist on her home planet of Krylor, Bereet used the inhabitants of Earth as inspiration for many of her films. Once she became aware of the Hulk, she felt she had the perfect subject. She traveled to Earth, convinced the Hulk that the Krylorians were invading, accompanied him for several weeks, and secretly used her Star Eyes to record his activities.

I assume the robot or pet you refer to are Bereet's "Star Eyes."

> Star Eyes: These levitating spheres record sights and sounds that Bereet can then incorporate into her films. They can also "fill in" events that they do not record but infer from later information.

[image]

Comment: How...how do those shoulder pads even *work*?